# How to avoid sharing state on WindowGroup / multiscreen macOS with SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, state

I am building a multiplatform app for iOS/iPadOS/macOS and would like to be able to open multiple windows of the same application on macOS.

This feature comes out of the box when you use WindowGroup and I'm able to open a new window from the status bar. However, I'm having trouble with separating state that should be shared and state that should be local to the windows.

Here's a stripped down version of my current app entry point. When opening a new window, I would like to ensure that the `api` state object is shared across all opened windows, but the `navManager` object should maintain it's own state per opened Window.

```swift
import SwiftUI

@Observable class NavManager {
    enum NavItem {
        case a
        case b
    }
    
    var currentNav: NavItem = .a
}

@Observable class Api {
    var someProperty: String = "Hello World"
}


struct NavigationView: View {
    @State private var navManager: NavManager = NavManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        switch navManager.currentNav {
        case .a:
            Text("Navigated to a")
        case .b:
            Text("Navigated to b")
        }
        Button {
            if navManager.currentNav == .a {
                navManager.currentNav = .b
            } else {
                navManager.currentNav = .a
            }
        } label: {
            Text("Toggle navigation")
        }
        Text("Some subview hierarchy that needs navManager")
            .environment(navManager)
    }
}

@main
struct MPFApp: App {
    
    @State private var api: Api = Api()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView()
                .environment(api)
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately with this code the state maintained in navManager is still shared between both windows, meaning navigation in one, will automatically navigate in the other window.

I couldn't find a clear description for this on the apple website or their WWDC talks. Any help would be much appreciated!

Kind regards,
Thiezn

Comment: Please show a [mcve] - something I can copy and paste into a new Xcode project to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Make sure `MyApi` and `NavigationManager` are structs. And you'll need to implement an `EnvironmentKey` especially for the api.

Comment: @malhal unfortunately I can't make them a struct as my real code uses the new 'Observable' macro. This doesn't require you to add a environmentKey anymore either in the .environment(api) calls

Comment: @sweeper I've updated the code to include a full copy/pasteable example. You can see when you open a second window, clicking the "Toggle navigation" button changes the state in both windows

Comment: I reproduced the issue. This definitely is not supposed to happen according to the documentation of `WindowGroup`. You should file a bug report. In the meantime, how about using an `ObservableObject` and `@StateObject` instead of `@Observable`?

Comment: Thanks, I've created a case with Apple FB13527567. It's just a hobby project and really want to use the newer @Observable macro's as it provides a much cleaner interface for state management.